# Merging branches under a single compressed commit

Tags: git

I was working on a feature branch and had close to 100 commits.  Now is the time for me to merge all those changes into our integration branch.  When I did a simple:

```
git merge feature_branch
```

It took every single commit and merged it into integration.

I was wondering if there is a `git merge` option under which it compresses all the merging commits into one big commit?  I am familiar with `rebase squashing` but that would need to be done on the feature branch and I would have to know what all the commits are that will be merged.  I was hoping there was a really easy way to say when you merge all that needs to be merged, compress it all in one big commit rather than keeping the original granularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git merge` with the `--squash` option.  So in your case you would use `git merge --squash feature_branch`.

You can find this flag and others in the [Git Documentation.](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)